# Is an email whitelist tied to a domain name, or an IP address?

Tags: whitelist, email

If I move my email server to a different server, and consequently a different IP address, but keep the same domain name, do I lose the work I've done to get whitelisted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"It depends on how the mail server provider sets up their whitelist."

Generally speaking:

- If they have configured their mail server to accept traffic from your IP you need to tell them the IP changed.
- If they set up a DNS-based whitelist to pass your domain, you probably don't have to do anything.
- If their whitelist is based on your SPF records you *may* need to update the record (if you use IPs in it instead of hostnames)

Comment: Just did a huge blitz for our mail servers, and practically everyone asks for IPs. That's why when I applied to all of them, I made sure to note where to apply and/or contact information of anyone there. Would make any changes or additions much easier.

Answer (score 2):

In my past workings, its usually the domain name that matters.  Thats pretty much why we have DNS servers to take care of resolutions.  When I would check against our own domain in the blacklistings, I would see entries like *.junk.ru and billgates.mac.chi.   It really depends on the listing service you subsribe to though.